# Unable to set language after using "i18n_pattern" to show language prefix in URL

Tags: django, internationalization, django-templates, translation, django-urls

As suggested, I'm wanting to show a language prefix in the URL and allow a visitor to my site to change the language using a form in the template. I've been using the sections on [URL prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.conf.urls.i18n) and [set_language redirect view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view) from the ["Translation" page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/) of the Django docs as a guide so far. My code is largely copied from this source.

### The Problem

Without using "i18n_pattern" (having both "url" calls in "pattern") in my URLconf, I manage to select language on the index.html page and have Django redirect me to the same page with the new language I have chosen. However, of course, the language URL prefix isn't shown.

When I use "i18n_pattern", the language prefix appears in the URL but seems to break the ability to change languages from the index.html form. For example, if I'm set on English and I change from "English (en)" to "Türkçe (tr)" in the form, the page essentially does a refresh without changing to Turkish (English is still shown). I can however change the language by changing my URL language prefix from "/en/" to "/tr/".

**pages/templates/pages/index.html**:

```
{% load i18n %}
<html>
  <head>
  ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
    <select name="language">
    {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
    {% for language in languages %}
    <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
        {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
     </option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>

    ...

    </body>    
</html>
```

**[project_name]/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url 
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'', include('pages.urls', namespace='pages')),
)
```

**Note**: The templates I'm using are located in the app called "pages".

Any help on getting these to work together would be appreciated! I have so far been unable to find anything on stackoverflow relating to this issue. If any more information is needed, please ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224357/django1-4-generic-way-to-set-language-links-in-template-to-work-with-i18n-patte) contains further details and some possible answers to the problem. None of the solutions are really appealing; nor should really be required. Unfortunately, this seems to be a problem with Django where both desired "features" can't work together "out-of-the-box" with the desired effect. In my case, since my site is a single page site, I can get away with setting the context variable with "redirect_to" = '/' (in the view) to negate the problem.